# Create tablerow using loop dont work

Tags: java, android

I create a code to add row programmatically in my xml, this is the code:

```
//layout
     /*create a linear layout */
    LinearLayout linearUserPicture = new LinearLayout(this);
    //linear.setGravity(Gravity);
    linearUserPicture.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            wlienar, hlienar);

    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, margim, 0);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;


    RoundedImageView imageView = new RoundedImageView(this, null);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.eu);

    //setting image position
    int w = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    // Log.d("divisaoxxxx", String.valueOf(w));
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(w, w));

    linearUserPicture.addView(imageView, layoutParams);

    //adicionar itens na tabela
    /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.feeds_table);
    /* Create a new row to be added. */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    for(int i=0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {



        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);


        tr.addView(linearUserPicture);

    }
    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

The code worked ok.
But I trying test to create many lines, so I added a loop to test:

```
 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.feeds_table);
    /* Create a new row to be added. */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    for(int i=0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {



        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);


        tr.addView(linearUserPicture);

    }
    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

The code dont run. How can I fix it?  This is the error:

```
02-16 12:25:14.911 20245-20245/com.example.alexandre_pc.beerin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alexandre_pc.beerin/com.example.alexandre_pc.beerin.FeedsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
 at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3620)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3491)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3436)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3412)
 at com.example.alexandre_pc.beerin.FeedsActivity.onCreate(FeedsActivity.java:86)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your crash is probably caused due to this line `tr.addView(linearUserPicture);`. Your exception tells you that a view you are trying to add already has a parent. This occurs when you try to add a `View` to a `ViewGroup` that is already in a `ViewGroup`. Because you don't re-instantiate `linearUserPicture` it is probably already added to the `TableRow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made your variable outside the loop, each iteration you are editing the same row and then add it to the list, which causes an exception because the row view is already added, and it's telling you you need to call removeView before you add it again

Just initialize your variable inside the loop
move this line inside the loop

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
```

EDIT:
The same fact applies to any view in the android system, you didn't say what the variable "linearUserPicture" is, I'm assuming it's a view as well, the same fact applies to it , you can't add the same view to more than one parent , you need to create a new object for it each time , so your loop should be like this

```
for(int i=0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);



    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

linearUserPicture = new View(); //DON'T COPY THIS! re create your view as you did it before every time
    tr.addView(linearUserPicture); // INITIALIZE linearUserPicture every loop!
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

Comment: But if I do it the line: 

tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Can not resolve tr. 
So if I put inside of loop I have the error too

Comment: I didn't notice the addition at the end I will edit my answer

Comment: you could have just moved tl.add to the loop as well , but I noticed that you have another view that is being added more than once to different parents "linearUserPicture" , so just look at the edit of my answer

Comment: Dont work too, I have this error:

ava.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

So I tried it, to fix the error:

            if(tr.getParent()!=null)
                ((ViewGroup)tr.getParent()).removeView(tr); // <- fix

But dont worked

Comment: Did you just copy my code exactly? and you are getting the error at : tr.add(linearUserPicture)?
and why are you trying to remove the child !

Comment: Yes I copy your code and I have the error, so I tried remove the child after test your code, only to test. Your code return the error : ava.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Comment: Brother, read my whole EDIT part carefully, and the comment I capitalized in my code! you DIDN'T show how did you initialize the linearUserPicture varialbe , So I said you have to re initialize it every loop iteration.

BOTTOM LINE IS: you can't add a view twice! you code is still doing it , just don't add any view twice and your code will work

Comment: Realy  sorry guy, I dont  re initialize. I flinched at this point. Now I fix it and worked very well. Thanks

Comment: No problem, Glad it worked :), I suggest you read more about java variable scopes , Good luck